# group similar rows in listview based on their content

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i have a listview that displays a set of rows, each row is clickable.
now, i wish to group similar type of rows under one header something like as shown in the figure (mocked up). could some please advise or provide an approach for this.
[image: mockup image]

Comment: What kind of adapter are you currently using? Are you interested in how to display "separator" list items?

Comment: +1 for the easy to understand paintings

Comment: I want to perform this same task, but all the values will be updated run-time. please suggest me how to do this, I tried alot but getting repeated section list. In all not getting success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra paremeter for the 'category' of each listview item. Then implement something like 'StickyListHeaders' based on that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [AmazingListView](https://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/) in the past with some effectiveness.
It is an implementation of the [Google I/O Schedule App](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) suggested approach.

Things that I like about it:

1. Sticky headers
2. Pagination with lazy loading

Of note:

1. It's an SVN-based project
2. You need to include it as a library
3. It's harder to use it with Android Studio; much easier with ADT.

([I did just post a question about this recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23854689/import-of-amazinglistview-in-android-studio-failing))

Here's an image from the project home page:
[image: AmazingListView example lists]

Answer (score -1):

If your adapter is Cursor based then use **[SectionCursorAdapter 2.0](https://github.com/twotoasters/SectionCursorAdapter/tree/master-2.0)**, you can't do simplier:

```
public class MyAdapter extends SectionCursorAdapter<String, MyAdapter.SectionViewHolder, MyAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0, R.layout.item_section, R.layout.item_title);
    }

    // this method will fullfill your wishes
    @Override protected String getSectionFromCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("group"));
    }

// replace getView/bindView/newView
// --------------------------------------------
    @Override protected SectionViewHolder createSectionViewHolder(View sectionView, String section) {
        return new SectionViewHolder(sectionView);
    }

    @Override protected ItemViewHolder createItemViewHolder(Cursor cursor, View itemView) {
        return new ItemViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override protected void bindSectionViewHolder(int position, SectionViewHolder sectionViewHolder, ViewGroup parent, String section) {
        sectionViewHolder.titleView.setText(section);
    }

    @Override protected void bindItemViewHolder(ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        itemViewHolder.title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("title"));
        itemViewHolder.titleView.setText(itemViewHolder.text);
    }

// view holders
// --------------------------------------------
    public class SectionViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
        public TextView titleView;

        public SectionViewHolder(View rootView) {
            super(rootView);
            titleView = findWidgetById(R.id.sectionText);
        }
    }

    public class ItemViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
        public String title;
        public TextView titleView;

        public ItemViewHolder(View rootView) {
            super(rootView);
            titleView = findWidgetById(R.id.titleText);
        }
    }

}
```