# List View with groups in android

Tags: android

I have a list view with some date and text in each row.Can I group this listView into groups as in iPhone with header between them.Is it possible in android. Please help.
i.e I need to have header bar between the Listview rows so that rows below each header will become a group if I am grouping it using date.

Comment: possible duplicate of [group similar rows in listview based on their content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507248/group-similar-rows-in-listview-based-on-their-content)

Answer (score 18):

Here are the plenty of articles for [Android - ListView with Section](http://www.google.co.in/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=android%20listview%20with%20section) from Google, from that i have listed out some of important articles/tutorials:

1. http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/
2. http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296
3. [Creating categories in a ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013765/creating-categories-in-a-listview)
4. [Android ListView Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966802/android-listview-headers)