# Complex use of list view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am displaying list of message in listview. But i need to dispaly message group by date of message. Somthing like this--> Date and list of message on this date, then next date and list message and so on. How to achive this.

Comment: You could use sectioned table view? Section title would be the date.. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318 go here to see sample code for sectioned table view...

Comment: This is for ios. This will help in android?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951546/list-view-with-groups-in-android. This should help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think You should use the Expandable ListView which provides the implementation like the way you said.
try this links:--

http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

this will help you for sure.