# Custom layout for sliding menu

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I want to group items in my custom [sliding menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) 
like facebook menu items[image]

Can somebody share some pointers/insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [List View with groups in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951546/list-view-with-groups-in-android) and [group similar rows in listview based on their content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507248/group-similar-rows-in-listview-based-on-their-content)

You can have a look here : http://blogingtutorials.blogspot.be/2010/11/android-listview-header-two-or-more-in.html

Comment: Hi, Expandable list views helped with custom UI. Thanks anyway :)